# JavaScript--merge two array objects into one arr object then loop through each index/object

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var arrObj1 = [{a:1},{b:2}, {c:3}]

var arrObj2 = [{operator: LESS THAN}, {operator:GREATER THAN}, {operator:"NOT EQUAL"}]
```

so I want to merge obj at arrObj2[0] into obj at arrObj1[0], arrObj2[1] into obj at arrObj1[1] and so forth...

```
//resultArrObj = [{a:1, operator: LESS THAN}, {b:2, operator:"GREATER THAN}];
```

After (or while merging) i need to loop through each object and return a new obj which will have the properties(field, input, operator) and push into array.

```
field = key from arrObj1 (a, b, c)
input = value from arrObj1(1,2,3)
operator = "operator" from arrObj 2. 

// var endResult = [{field:a, input:1, operator: LESS THAN}, {field:b, input:2, operator:GREATER THAN}];
```

thanks!!

Comment: Why `NOT EQUAL` is skipped?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you are looking for.  It assumes that you know your data and doesn't do any error checking but just combines them the way that you asked.

```
var arrObj1 = [{a:1},{b:2}, {c:3}];

var arrObj2 = [{operator: "LESS THAN"}, {operator:"GREATER THAN"}, {operator:"NOT EQUAL"}];

var endResult = [];
var counter = 0;
var objNew = {};

arrObj1.forEach(function(fieldInput){
    for ( field in fieldInput ){
        objNew.field=field;
        objNew.input=fieldInput[field];
        objNew.operator=arrObj2[counter]['operator'];
        counter++;
        endResult.push(objNew);
        objNew={};
    };
})

// var endResult = [{field:a, input:1, operator: LESS THAN}, {field:b, input:2, operator:GREATER THAN}, {field:c, input:3, operator:NOT EQUAL}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this problem into 2 steps:
1) Merging objects
2) Processing objects

We can write a generalized merging function:

```
if (!Object.prototype.extend) {

      Object.prototype.extend = function (object) {

        for (key in object) {

          if (typeof object[key] === 'object' && 
              typeof this[key]   === 'object' && 
              this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

            this[key].extend(object[key]);      

          } else {      
            this[key] = object[key];      
          }

        }    

        return this;  
      };
};
```

The code above creates a method that all Objects share.  It works like this:

```
var obj1 = { 'a': 7 },
    obj2 = { 'b': 2 };

obj1.extend(obj2);

console.log(obj1); // { 'a': 7, 'b': 2 };
```

I usually wouldn't modify Objects like I have done with the .extend method, but it should be trivial to build something that does the same thing but has a different API.  (for example, function extend (obj1, obj2) { do stuff.. and return extended object }

Anyways.  That should solve the first part about merging objects.

The second part, processing this merged object, is simply using a for loop that iterates over the merged object, and pushes new objects into an array.  It would look something like this:

```
for (var prop in mergedObject) {
  var tempObject = {};
  if (prop === 'operator') {
    tempObject.operator = mergedObject.operator;
  } else {
    tempObject.field = prop;
    tempObject.input = tempObject[prop];
  }
  endResult.push(tempObject);
}
```

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: You _do_ realize that this extends every single object in JS right?

Comment: Ironically - this adds an enumerable property too which you'd later iterate and copy in your for... in loop

Comment: This will fail when `this[key]` is null, since `typeof null === 'object'`.

Comment: I do realize it extends every single object.  I did mention right in the answer that I don't usually do this.  I even mention that it would be easy to refactor it so that it is a function declaration, which would avoid the pitfall of using my initial suggestion that you said about iterating over that .extend property.  

Good point torazaburo, I did not think of that.  Perhaps I should have put in the effort to provide the OP a better solution.  My hope was that he could extract what he needed from what I provided to come up with his own solution.